# SFTP/FTP Server which throttles bandwidth speed based on number of connected users?

Tags: ftp, bandwidth-control

Here is a dynamic rule I'd like to configure on a SFTP/FTP server:

```
If only 1 user is connected, set download bandwidth cap to 200 KB/Sec

If 4 users are connected, set download bandwidth cap to 50 KB/Sec
```

Right now, I can configure a fixed setting where all users' download bandwidth cap is set to 50 KB/Sec. But it isn't really optimized if there is only 1 person downloading.

Is there any software or method which allows my description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your FTP server enable throttling for the whole process itself? That seems like what you really want to do; It would automatically adjust the bandwidth per-user to stay within the total limit. The only time it wouldn't be fairly close to even is if one user isn't able to achieve that much throughput anyway.

Comment: Do you mean if I set the throttle cap to 200 KB/Sec for every user, then when there are 4 users, the server will automatically divide the bandwidth to 50 KB/Sec between them automatically? So I shouldn't do the bandwidth dividing manually but set it to the max upload bandwidth?

Comment: Yes, I think; if you set the speed cap for the process to 200KB/sec for the *program* itself (ie. for *all* users, collectively), it would then divide that much bandwidth relatively equally per user. It would do so essentially automatically and dynamically; if 4 users are transferring and one finishes, the remaining 3 would each go from getting roughly 50KB/s to 66.6KB/s.